# How do I set the debugger next statement background highlight colour in visual studio 2022 in dark mode?

Tags: visual-studio, darkmode

When I hit a breakpoint in visual studio (c#) I see the following highlight showing the 'next statement' which is making it impossible to read the code about to execute.

(image upload is not working here atm) https://imgur.com/a/97VVIBd

The background is yellow, and the text is various shades of light colours for the syntax highlighting which blends into the yellow background making it unreadable.

I have looked in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colours. I could not find a specific colour option that matched 'next statement'.  So I changed anything with a yellow background to something else, and still getting the same. None of the breakpoint entries use yellow as the background.

I am using the visVim extension, don't know if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colors -> Current Statement